# Unable to hide a Gif image after file download from server.(C# and javascript)

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a tricky situation :

There is UI which just has a button. On button click I process a PowerPoint document in the server (I add some relevant content to the slide) and then download it to the client system.

Now when the user clicks the download button, I show a small animated *gif* saying "processing", but when the PowerPoint file downloads into the client system I am not able to hide or disable the "processing image".

This is the Serverside Code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION /OCTET-STREAM";

String Header = "Attachment; Filename=" + FileName;
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", Header);
//for the server

//for normal 
System.IO.FileInfo Dfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(PPTPath);

HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(Dfile.FullName);
```

This is the Client Side Code :

```
ShowProcessMessage = function(PanelName)
{
    document.getElementById(PanelName).hidden = "";
    document.getElementById("Image1").style.visibility = "visible";

    return true; //Returns the control to the Server click event
}
```

Can anyone give some Ideas on how to implement?

Comment: document.getElementById(PanelName).hidden = "";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution is do client side ajax call. 
use beforeSend to show spinner and complete to hide spinner (complete triggers on succes of failure)

```
$.ajax({
        url: linktoPdf
                , beforeSend: function (xhr) { $('#idOfSpinner').addClass("showSpinner"); }
                , complete: function () { $('#idOfSpinner').removeClass("showSpinner"); }
                , success: function (response)  { /*your code here */ }
            , error: function () { /*your code here */ }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks buddy .Haven't really used Ajax to a great extent till now.Can u guide me with the implementation part of the code above in the client side( how to use the code in the html  file?) or is there any alternative with other javascript functions?

Comment: sure.. see here... (not my code juste googled jsfiddel ajax ) http://jsfiddle.net/GRMule/WQXXT/  is this something you can work with?

Comment: Thank you buddy .I will test the code using the format in and let you know asap.

Comment: This is the How I use:                                                       getSuccessOutput() {
         $.ajax({
             url: 'http://localhost:52311/WebForm1.aspx'
                , beforeSend: function () { $('#Image1').addClass("showSpinner"); }
                , complete: function () { $('#Image1').removeClass("showSpinner"); }
         });
         return false;
     }
        <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" OnClientClick ="getSuccessOutput()" OnClick="Button4_Click" Text="Button" />

Comment: I used the above but its not working . Am I missing something??

Comment: Actuall the following portion worked:
      jQuery.ajax({
    
          beforeSend:function(xhr, settings){
              xhr.startTime = new Date().getTime();
              $('#Image1').show();},

          complete: function (xhr) {
              var elapsed = new Date().getTime() - xhr.startTime;
              if (elapsed < 10000) {
                  $('#Image1').delay(10000 - elapsed).hide(1);
              } else {
                  $('#Image1').hide();
              }
          }
      });

Comment: Thank you LordKain

Comment: @alok good to hear you found youre solution! If youre happy with response pleaee mark as valid answer.